# How to target a specific column in database with php?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to select a specific column in my mysql database which is in 3 different tables. First I target a table which the specific column is in. Then select all from that column. I only know how to target the table that the specific column is in. How can I target the specific column from the table?

```
$query = query("SELECT product_title, product_price, product_image, product_description, product_id, short_desc FROM products1 WHERE cat_id=" . escape_string($_GET['id']). " UNION SELECT product_title, product_price, product_image, product_description, product_id, short_desc FROM products2 WHERE cat_id=" . escape_string($_GET['id']). " UNION SELECT product_title, product_price, product_image, product_description, product_id, short_desc FROM products3 WHERE cat_id=" . escape_string($_GET['id']). ""
);
```

The code above targets a table, now I need to display all the info of the specific column that is in the table.

**How can I target the specific column from the table?**

Comment: Can you give more information about the 3 tables, what columns they have and what the relationships to one another are?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this....

```
$id = escape_string($_GET['id']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products1 left join products2 on products1.cat_id=products2.cat_id left join products3 on products1.cat_id=products3.cat_id WHERE cat_id='$id'";
$query = query($sql);
```